# Could someone Help me understand this code

Tags: java

I have an assignment due soon however I am still very new to Java and only know basics. Anyway I have to create a Text analyser by which calculates the amount of words, Characters and lines of a document I read in.

I found This code below and I have Started to comment it, however I do not know if my comments are correct and I am not to sure on what the uncommented parts do. If someone could write a short explanation for me or something I would be greatly appreciative.

```
    //Loops through the file until it has counted everything. 
     while (in.hasNext()) {
        String tmpStr = in.nextLine();
        if (!tmpStr.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            String replaceAll = tmpStr.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
            // Counts the number of characters within the file.
            charsCount += replaceAll.length();
            // Counts the number of words within the file.
            wordsCount += tmpStr.split(" ").length;
        } 
        // Counts number of lines
        ++linesCount;
     } //Ends While Loop.
```

I assume that where the code is counting the characters it is ignoring spaces, What would I change so that it counts spaces also.

You all helped loads, with my work I now understand it more and enough to make changes, I wish I could select you all for solving my answer, thanks again :)

Comment: Where the code counts characters (the .length() method call), it **does** count spaces just like any other character.

Comment: No it does not. Whitespace is removed by  the call of `replaceAll`.

Comment: Your comments are correct. I suggest you also test it against some examples and check the result. Maybe make that a unit test for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have most of it.  I'll try to explain in detail each aspect.

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
  ...
}
```

This is the main loop.  It simply tests to see if there is anything else in the input that you are reading.  If there is, then it executes the code in between the braces.

```
String tmpStr = in.nextLine();
```

Reads the next line from the scanner and assigns it to tmpStr.  There is a small gotcha here.  nextLine() does not return the carriage return or newline characters.  If you are supposed to count those as characters in your project, your count will be off.

```
if (!tmpStr.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
  ...
}
```

This if statement checks to see if it is just an empty line (ie no characters) and if it is, skips processing the line.  It is an optimization and isn't strictly required to accomplish your goal.

```
String replaceAll = tmpStr.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

This is a regular expression call.  It removes all whitespace from the line and stores it as a temporary variable.  Whitespace includes characters such as space, tab, vertical tab, form feed, carriage return, etc.  You almost certainly don't want to do this unless your problem is defined in such a way that you do not need to count whitespace.  If the problem wants number of characters (whitespace and all) and your input is guaranteed to be ASCII, then the easiest solution for counting characters will be to return the file size since 1 character = 1 byte in ASCII.  Otherwise the problem gets a little hairy.  If you supply what defines a character for the purposes of your project, I can probably provide better guidance here.

```
charsCount += replaceAll.length();
```

This keeps a count of the non-whitespace characters seen.  The += operator takes whatever the value of charsCount was before and adds to it the length of the line in characters after the whitespace was removed.

```
wordsCount += tmpStr.split(" ").length;
```

Split takes a string and returns an array of substrings that have been split by the supplied character.  In this case that character is space.  So the line "The quick brown fox" would return an array of four items "The", "quick", "brown", and "fox".  Note that spaces are removed.  The length of array is then added to an ongoing count of words.  This is a fairly naive way of counting words since there are word boundaries that are not spaces.  This includes things like tab, em dashes, etc.  This may work for your purposes, but again it will depend on the parameters of your project.

```
++linesCount;
```

This counts the lines.  The ++ simply means "add 1" to the variable.  So for each iteration of the while loop, linesCount will increase by one.

Answer (score 0):

Some more comments:

```
// Get the next line from the input
String tmpStr = in.nextLine();
// If the line is not empty ...
if (!tmpStr.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
  // Remove all whitespace from the line
  String replaceAll = tmpStr.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to explain in a few steps how that code works

1. As long your "in" has more values, a temporary String takes a line from your in. This is a loop, which will be executed as long your in values has.
2. If that temporary String is not empty ("" = an empty String), the number of characters will be count by the length(number of chars) of your temporary String, for example: String "hello" contains 5 characters.
3. The wordcounts happens with a split of 1 space (" "). This makes from your String a collection of words. The number of words from the line will be added to the global variable wordsCount.
4. Finally the number of lines is numberd + 1 (++LinesNumber) So you also know how many rows there are.

Hope this makes things clear

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count all char including whitespaces you need remove the `replaceAll`, then count the line chars and later the number of words

```
//Loops through the file until it has counted everything. 
 while (in.hasNext()) {
    String tmpStr = in.nextLine();
    if (!tmpStr.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        // Counts the number of characters within the file.
        charsCount += tmpStr.length();
        // Counts the number of words within the file.
        wordsCount += tmpStr.split(" ").length;
    } 
    // Counts number of lines
    ++linesCount;
 } //Ends While Loop.
```